# Check to see if Entity has been Deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We're implementing Entity Framework inside a winforms application using DbContext/Code First and have the following question regarding the proper way to check/handle when an entity has been deleted/updated in another context.

For example, we have some auxiliary table data (e.g. StateCodes) and the user could go in another and add/remove states as needed. This auxiliary editor form utilizes it's own DbContext and saves the changes once the user exits the form.  Upon returning to the main form, the main context is unaware of the changes made to the database so we'd like to reload the DbSet for the entity.  Unfortunately, it appears that if we remove the "MI" state code it still exists in the Local property of the DbSet with an EntityState of unchanged even after we call "Load" to bring in everything.

Outside of completely disposing of the main context would the following be the best way to check and see if what entities have been removed from the database?

```
foreach (State state in db.States.Local)
{
    DbEntityEntry entry = db.Entry(state);
    DbPropertyValues databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();
    if (databaseValues == null)
    {
        db.States.Remove(state);
    }
    else
    {
        entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't keep the context live past its unit of work. The context should only survive as long as its needed, otherwise you're bound to run in to caching pitfalls like you're observing. (Also, the context really isn't *that* heavy where instantiating it when you need it is overly time-consuming/resource intensive).

If you really must keep it alive, you may want to look in to passing the context to the auxiliary form.

*Mirrored from my comment, figured it's best served as an answer*

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  If I'm understanding correctly, then the following logic may be our best bet:   User clicks to edit auxiliary data -- Call SaveChanges on current context -- Dispose current context and display editor to user -- Upon return, re-instanstiate context and go through initial loading of data again.

Comment: @NuNnDaDdY: yes. Although I'd argue that you should be creating the context within actions e.g. `buttononClick(){ using (Context c = new Context()) { c.Entities.Add(e); c.SaveChanges(); } }`

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your reasoning for creating the inside each action.  I ask because I'm attempting to implement data-binding throughout the main form with a number of master-detail relationships.  If I went with creating a context inside of each action I imagine that I would no longer really be able to rely on the data binding for change tracking, correct?

Comment: @NuNnDaDdY: you're going to know the application better than i am. The beauty of EF is that they are POCOs so unless you're constantly making database calls, the entities can be stored and manipulated in their own scope and then CRUD can be performed when necessary. however, if you're using some form of MVVM and want the updates to apply spontaneously, you may be okay keeping the context alive. It all depends on how you're implementing it and what your application does. I'm just demonstrating that unless a database action is being performed, the context isn't necessary to keep alive.

Comment: Thank you for helping to clarify things.  I'll talk this over with the other developer and look into the suggestions you made.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

First, what Brad said.  Only keep the context alive for the specific unit of work and dispose it.  Not doing this will lead to nothing but headaches.

You can also check the entity's state by using the ObjectStateManager and pass in the object or entity key.  You can also use the

`public void Refresh(
    RefreshMode refreshMode,
    IEnumerable collection
)`

method off of the Context.  Also, you can check the entry state.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503718.aspx