# Rebind combobox to static ObservableCollection after inserting to database

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, static

I have a static variable to retrieve group list from database.

```
public static ObservableCollection<Group> GroupList 
{
 get
 {
  return Group.getGroups(); //<-- this retrieve group from database
 }
}
```

Then I bind my combobox to this static property on my xaml.

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbGroup" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static wpf:Group.GroupList}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectionChanged="cmbGroup_SelectionChanged" />
```

Up until this point, everything is working fine. Then I type new group into textbox and  insert 1 row to database. After successfully insert to database, my combobox didn't change. What I want is my combobox being updated instantly.
To my understanding, i need someway to update the property of **static GroupList** so my binding to combobox is working again.  Any idea how to achieve this?

As a side note, i use this approach so i only need to code 1 time to retrieve group list from database and remove the necessity to write many lines on code behind. With this approach, i only need **ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static wpf:Group.GroupList}}"** to bind with combobox.

Comment: When you add a new group into the "textbox" are you adding it to the collection that the combo box is bound to or are you only updating the database with the value?  I haven't worked with WPF enough as the binding may be slightly different than winforms but if you're only inserting the new value in the database without updating the local ObservableCollection then wouldn't you need to reload/refresh the collection with the values from the database in order for it to recognize that there is a new value?

Comment: That is exactly the problem. The collection that the combobox is bound to isn't added manually and i don't use code behind to call the method. Everything is done via xaml. With that said, i didn't add the item collection after i insert new data to database and i didn't want to. I simply want WPF to reevaluate the bindingsource property which is Group.GroupList.

Comment: Your local ObservableCollection will not be aware of any changes to the database that are made as the context is only aware of any changes that occur to the entities that are attached to it and is tracking.  If you update the database outside of the context, it doesn't see this and won't display the new records as it's only displaying your local collection.  You'll need to either requery the database or add it to the local collection.  Couldn't you manually add it to the local collection and then call SaveChanges()?  Then context will add it to the database for you automatically.

Comment: I tried to set the itemsource again in code behind,and it worked. I just thought it is better if there is some cleaner method like 'cmbGroup.Bind();' , so i or other team member didn't need to remember which method the comboxbox is bound to. Because on larger scale apps, there will be too much to remember, so basically i am just trying to minimize that. But, if there isn't such way, i guess i stick with requerying the database myself. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @NuNnDaDdY As correctly mentioned by vugtis, your ObservableCollection will not be aware of any changes done to database. I recommend not to make DB calls from static property since it will be initialized only once. If your intention is to catch the collection, call Groups.getGroups() and assign its value to static ObservableCollection. See this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500240/how-can-i-replace-static-observablecollection-so-it-accesable-on-all-windows-in)

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome.

If you're using the Entity Framework it's much simpler to just update the local objects and let the DbContext/ObjectContext handle the change tracking for you.  Then there's no need to remember when someone is suppose to re-query the database.  The team member(s) can then concern themselves with only the objects and not have to worry about everything being in sync.  If the object context lifespan is persisting while the form is available, then you could set a timer to run at a set interval, call SaveChanges, and re-instantiate the DbContext with the latest data from the database. Since you're using an ObservableCollection, this provides for two-way binding and when the local object is added, whatever the collection is bound to in the UI will reflect this change to the end-user as well.

However if the life of the DbContext is only for the "unit of work" that's being performed, then each subsequent call with the DbContext should bring in the latest data as you'll be using a new instance of the DbContext/ObjectContext.  More information on this can be found from a previous discussion I had with another user who elaborated on this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976639/check-to-see-if-entity-has-been-deleted)